# How to turn arguments into floats

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started learning python and would like to know if there was a way to turn my arguments into a float another way than how I'm doing it. A more simple way instead of turning them into a variable first.

```
def add(arg1, arg2):
  a = float(arg1)
  b = float(arg2)
  return a + b
```

Comment: `return float(arg1) + float(arg2)`?

Comment: You can directly write `return float(arg1) + float(arg2)`.

Comment: I should edit my question. Is there a way to make the arguments a float right from the beginning.

Comment: `arg1, arg2 = map(float, (arg1, arg2))` Would work but I would say it impacts readability.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) for such thing

```
from functools import wraps
def floatArgs(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args):
        return f(*map(float, args))
    return wrapper

@floatArgs
def add(arg1, arg2):
  return arg1 + arg2


>>> add(4,5)
9.0
```

One generic aproach could be use a generic decorator for mapping types over arguments using an argument itself:

```
def typeArgs(t):
    def retF(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args):
            return f(*map(t, args))
        return wrapper
    return retF

@typeArgs(float)
def add(arg1, arg2):
  return arg1 + arg2

@typeArgs(str)
def concatenate(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2

>>> add(4, 5)
9.0

>>> concatenate(4,5)
'45'
```